# How to create a dataframe with unique value and quantify the result from other column

Tags: dataframe

The dataframe

```
      0    1    2    3 ...  100
0     A   21    Y    N ...  N
1     A   21    Y    Y ...  N
2     A   21    N    Y ...  N
3     B   21    Y    N ...  Y
4     B   21    Y    N ...  N
5     C   32    N    N ...  Y
```

I have try using this unique(), but i dont know how to count and summarize the Y and N into the expected result

```
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].unique()
```

expected result, any amount of Y in the column will result in Y. Only if all N will result in N.

```
      0    1    2    3 ...  100
0     A   21    Y    Y ...  N
1     B   21    Y    N ...  Y
2     C   32    N    N ...  Y
```